# Raise event in vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Frm_Company_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If (e.Control AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.S)) Then
        RaiseEvent btnsave.click
    End If
End Sub
```

showing error near btnsave.click ... saying that "end of statement is expected" 
what is the problem in above code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use [`RaiseEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fwd3bwed.aspx) like this. [`RaiseEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fwd3bwed.aspx) can only be used from inside the class that declares the event, not from the outside.

You can invoke the method that handles the event in two ways:

Either call `btnsave.PerformClick`. This fires the button's `Click` event and invokes *all* the event handlers attached to the event.

Or call the event handling method yourself, which of course does not handle other event handlers that may be attached to the event.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I know that `Button.PerformClick` performs the button's click. If that doesn't work, maybe you don't have an event handler attached at all?